# Fix XamlObjectWriterException, Cannot create unknown type in F#, FsXaml, WPF app?

Tags: wpf, fsxaml, elmish-wpf

I am getting this error in a WPF app that is built with F#, FsXaml, and Elmish.WPF.

```
System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException:
Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.componentone.com/winfx/2006/xaml}C1ProgressIndicator'.
at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartObject(XamlType xamlType)
at FsXaml.InjectXaml.from(String file, Boolean loadFromResource, Object root)
```

- A Views project contains XAML and includes a reference to C1.WPF.4.dll.
- The XAML declares an instance of a control from C1.WPF.4.dll.
- However, there is no F# code that uses any types from C1.WPF.4.dll.
- Consequently, Views.dll does not contain a reference to C1.WPF.4.dll, as confirmed by IL Spy.
- Consequently, when I build App.exe, C1.WPF.4.dll is not included in the output folder.
- Consequently, I get a run-time error.

While I could include a reference to C1.WPF.4.dll in my App project, I would rather not.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: While the issue is not really specific to FsXaml and Elmish WPF, it is more likely to occur with those technologies than with other current alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work:

1. In your XAML file, replace the XAML namespace with a CLR namespace. For example, instead of `xmlns:c1="http://schemas.componentone.com/winfx/2006/xaml"` use something like `xmlns:c1="clr-namespace:C1.WPF;assembly=C1.WPF.4"`.

This is required because when App.exe is running, it may not have loaded the controls library yet. It is in the controls library that [an attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml) creates the mapping from XAML namespace to CLR namespace. By explicitly stating the CLR namespace and assembly, the XamlReader can find the class to instantiate.

2. Create a dummy instance in the Views code. The dummy instance is an instance of something from the controls library. This creates the dependency in Views.dll on the controls library.

   ```
   // force the compiler to add a reference to C1.WPF.4.dll
   let private forceC1DllReference = C1.WPF.Anchor.TopLeft

   type MainWindowView = XAML< "MainWindow.xaml" >
   ```

This second one feels like a hack. I wonder if there is a better way to say, "Please add a reference to this DLL even if I'm not using types from it."

Comment: So do you have FsXaml and Elmish.WPF working together? I am interested in using them together but haven't tried yet.

Comment: @TysonWilliams Yes, I did as a proof of concept. No experience yet with a deployed app.